# Restarting Camera.StartStreamingBitmaps after Camera.PictureCaptured

Tags: .net-micro-framework, .net-gadgeteer

I have a .Net Gadgeteer camera app that streams bitmaps from the camera to a screen. On the press of a button it stops streaming the bitmaps from the camera, takes a picture, writes it to SD card, and then restarts the streaming. Here's a simplified version of the code (without the saving to SD card stuff):

```
using Microsoft.SPOT;
using GT = Gadgeteer;
using Gadgeteer.Modules.GHIElectronics;
namespace SimpleStopStreamingApp
{
    public partial class Program
    {
        void ProgramStarted()
        {
            camera.CameraConnected += new Camera.CameraConnectedEventHandler(camera_CameraConnected);
            camera.BitmapStreamed += new Camera.BitmapStreamedEventHandler(camera_BitmapStreamed);
            camera.PictureCaptured += new Camera.PictureCapturedEventHandler(camera_PictureCaptured);
            button.ButtonPressed += new Button.ButtonEventHandler(button_ButtonPressed);
        }
        void camera_CameraConnected(Camera sender)
        {
            camera.StartStreamingBitmaps(new Bitmap(camera.CurrentPictureResolution.Width, camera.CurrentPictureResolution.Height));
        }
        void camera_BitmapStreamed(Camera sender, Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            display_T35.SimpleGraphics.DisplayImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
        }
        void button_ButtonPressed(Button sender, Button.ButtonState state)
        {
            camera.StopStreamingBitmaps();
            camera.TakePicture();
        }
        void camera_PictureCaptured(Camera sender, GT.Picture picture)
        {
            camera.StartStreamingBitmaps(new Bitmap(camera.CurrentPictureResolution.Width, camera.CurrentPictureResolution.Height));
        }
    }
}
```

However when I try to restart the streaming (in the PictureCaptured event handler) I get the exception.

```
#### Exception System.Exception - 0xffffffff (1) ####
#### Message: 
#### GHI.Premium.USBHost.USBH_Webcam::StartStreaming_Internal [IP: 0000] ####
#### GHI.Premium.USBHost.USBH_Webcam::StartStreaming [IP: 0005] ####
#### Gadgeteer.Modules.GHIElectronics.Camera::StartStreamingBitmaps [IP: 007e] ####
#### Gadgeteer.Modules.GHIElectronics.Camera::OnPictureCapturedEvent [IP: 0037] ####
#### System.Reflection.MethodBase::Invoke [IP: 0000] ####
#### Gadgeteer.Program::DoOperation [IP: 001a] ####
#### Microsoft.SPOT.Dispatcher::PushFrameImpl [IP: 0054] ####
#### Microsoft.SPOT.Dispatcher::PushFrame [IP: 001a] ####
#### Microsoft.SPOT.Dispatcher::Run [IP: 0006] ####
#### Gadgeteer.Program::Run [IP: 0020] ####
```

`A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in GHI.Premium.USBHost.dll
Error invoking method "Gadgeteer.Modules.GHIElectronics.Camera" (check arguments to Program.BeginInvoke are correct)`

(N.B. I get this same exception if I store the bitmap as an instance variable and pass it in to both calls to StartStreamingBitmaps instead of creating a new Bitmap each time.)

What's going on? How should one stop the camera streaming to capture and image and then restart it streaming?

Answer (score 1):

It almost sounds like `StartStreamingBitmaps` is expected to run on a thread (by the note to `check arguments to Program.BeginInvoke are correct`).

Looking at this:

```
void camera_PictureCaptured(Camera sender, GT.Picture picture)
{
  camera.StartStreamingBitmaps(new Bitmap(camera.CurrentPictureResolution.Width, camera.CurrentPictureResolution.Height));
}
```

I don't know anything about this **Gadgeteer** module, but if you wired it up correctly, I'd think your new `GT.Picture` is already contained in the `picture` parameter that was passed in.

It almost looks like you are trying to stream images from the camera **after** the camera has finished taking the picture.

Can you edit your post and give more details? Can you verify that this `camera_PictureCaptured` event is where your exception is being thrown? It'd be easy enough to do by modifying your event handler to be:

```
void camera_PictureCaptured(Camera sender, GT.Picture picture)
{
  try
  {
    camera.StartStreamingBitmaps(new Bitmap(camera.CurrentPictureResolution.Width, camera.CurrentPictureResolution.Height));
  } catch (Exception err)
  {
    throw new Exception("PictureCaptured: " + err.Message);
  }
}
```

If this event handler is not the one throwing the exception, try placing similar `try...catch` routines in your other event handlers until you discover which one is really causing the problem.

Comment: I'm sure that is where it is thrown, since Gadgeteer lets you step through the running code on the device in Visual Studio, but I will add the code and check. The start of your answer has reminded me that the source for the Gadgeteer camera module is on Codeplex, so I could check there. I'll edit my question with the new info.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the callback when you stop streaming the bitmaps:

```
void button_ButtonPressed(Button sender, Button.ButtonState state)
{
    camera.BitmapStreamed -= new Camera.BitmapStreamedEventHandler(camera_BitmapStreamed);
    camera.StopStreamingBitmaps();
    camera.TakePicture();
}

void camera_PictureCaptured(Camera sender, GT.Picture picture)
{
    camera.BitmapStreamed += new Camera.BitmapStreamedEventHandler(camera_BitmapStreamed);
    camera.StartStreamingBitmaps(new Bitmap(camera.CurrentPictureResolution.Width, camera.CurrentPictureResolution.Height));
}
```